Cannot set up custom camera in visionOS immersive space
I am unable to use a custom camera in visionOS immersive space.
I wrote a minimal demo app (below), based on Apple's Immersive Environment App template.
This app creates a box that is positioned so that it can be seen in the simulator when RealityKit's default camera is used:

The app also creates a perspective camera, using the example code from the docu.
The camera position is still (x,y,z) = (0,0,2).
However, I changed the lookAt point from the origin to (x,y,z) = (1,1,1) to demonstrate the problem.
Since looking from (0,0,2) towards  (1,1,1) is a different perspective than looking from (0,0,2) towards  (0,0,0), the camera image should change, but it is exactly the same.
Obviously, the default camera is still used and not the custom perspective camera.
What am I missing?
Here is my code:
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) var appModel

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let cameraEntity = makeCamera()
            content.add(cameraEntity) // If out commented, RealityKit's default camera is used

            let boxEntity = makeBox()
            content.add(boxEntity)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCamera() -> Entity {
        let cameraEntity = Entity()
        
        // Place the camera 2 meters along the z-axis,
        // looking at (x,y,z) = (1,1,1)
        let cameraPosition: SIMD3<Float> = [0, 0, 2]
        cameraEntity.look(at: SIMD3<Float>(1,1,1), from: cameraPosition, relativeTo: nil)
        
        cameraEntity.components.set(PerspectiveCameraComponent())
        
        return cameraEntity
    }
    
    func makeBox() -> ModelEntity {
        let size: Float = 0.3
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width: size, height: size, depth: size)
        var material = UnlitMaterial(); material.color.tint = .red
        let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        boxEntity.transform.translation = [0, 0, -3]
        return boxEntity
    }
}


You can only change the camera on nonAR scenarios in visionOS the user's view is the camera, the work has to move if you want the user to see a particular angle.

@loremipsum Thanks for pointing this out. This makes sense. The user has to move to reposition the camera. But then it seems that the documentation is at least misleading.

The docs for the cameras all say the same thing > In AR scenarios, the system provides the camera automatically; however, in non-AR scenarios, the app needs to set the camera. If the app doesn’t provide a camera, the system uses the default perspective camera.

The system camera is the user’s view. This is how you setup the camera for nonAR.
